# Difference between rake and bin/rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets, precompile

Can someone explain the differences between the following commands?

`rake assets:precompile`

`bin/rake assets:precompile`

`RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`

`RAILS_ENV=production bin/rake assets:precompile`

Comment: One explicitly runs the rake in bin. One doesn't. Two set the environment to production, the other two don't (e.g., the default, development, is used).

Comment: what does it mean to "run the rake in binary"?

Comment: Nothing; I said "runs the rake in bin". `bin` is (assumed to be) a subdirectory in the current directory. The calls to `bin/rake` explicitly run the rake command contained in the `bin` directory. Calls to `rake` run the rake command whatever, or wherever, it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `rake` and `bin/rake`

Rake is a program that you installed on your computer. To use it in your terminal, you use `rake do:something`. Using directly `rake` means that a shortcut has been created, an alias saying "when I type `rake` I want to use the program located in [...]".

The `bin/rake` style is not using the alias created but the path of the program. Usually the programs' executor (not the program's content, just the launcher) are located in the folder `/bin/`. To determine the full path of a specific program, use `which`:

```
[yoshiji:~] $ which rake
/home/yoshiji/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@yourproject/bin/rake
[yoshiji:~] $ which ls
/bin/ls
```

- `RAILS_ENV=production rake do:something`

This `RAILS_ENV` part is here to specify an environment Rails should load when running the `rake` command. By default the environment is `development`.

---

**To summarize:**

- `rake assets:precompile` : Use the alias/shortcut `rake`
- `/bin/rake assets:precompile` : Use the full path to the `rake` program
- `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` : Specify Rails to load the `production` environment when executing the rake task `assets:precompile`

Comment: so `rake` and `bin/rake` behave exactly the same? The only difference is a level of explicitness?

Comment: Unless you've defined a shortcut `rake` to do something else that launching the program located in `bin/rake`, yes they behave the same. The only difference is that one uses a shortcut whereas the other uses the full path.

Comment: It would be nice if you explain where to find the alias. I don have it neither in .bash_profile nor .bashrc. I am missing something?

Answer (score 5):

`rake` and `bin/rake` are both executable Ruby files used to bootstrap the Rake gem. `rake` is your environment's default invocation of the Rake gem and was created by RubyGems when you installed Rake. It should live somewhere in your PATH:

```
[jkrause:~] $ which rake
/usr/bin/rake
```

Or if you are using a version manager such as RVM (and you should be):

```
[jkrause:~] $ which rake
/Users/jkrause/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/rake
```

`bin/rake`, on the other hand, is created by Rails when you create a new Rails application and lives inside the `bin` directory located in the root of your Rails app:

```
[jkrause:~] $ ls -la ~/src/my_rails_app/bin/rake
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jkrause  staff  164 Jan  5 14:11 bin/rake
```

In older versions of Rails (3.x and older), `bin/rake` didn't exist and so standard practice was to call the default `rake` installed by RubyGems. With Rails 4.x, you need to call `bin/rake` because the Rails needs to alter the environment and load some auxiliary gems before your Rake invocation. In all honesty, I still execute `rake` from time to time out of habit, and I have never seen anything break, but its probably a good idea to start using `bin/rake` since the Rails Guides explicitly show that.

Finally, `RAILS_ENV` is used to set which Rails environment (development, testing, or production) that particular execution of `rake` or `bin/rake` should use.